# How can I create a page with four content types displayed with infinite scroll?

Tags: views

I need a page where i display a list of 4 contents types articles.

The articles for each content type must grouped, and when scrolling i want load page for each groupe.

What is the better way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to create a page where you can display all content from four different content types but as a single list of articles? Or as four different lists in one page? You want one single scroll for the whole page right?

Comment: Yes , as four different lists in one page but one scroll for the 4 lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view with one content type with a page display and then in that view add three displays, one each for each of the other content types, and attach these displays to the first page view. That will give four different lists in the same page. You will have one scroll for the page.  I do not think an infinite scroll would make sense in this context.

If you want as one single list with all the articles but with each type of content grouped together do the following. This is the only way infinite scroll is going to work well for you.

You can create a content view and filter by the four content types that you want to list in the view. And then add a sort by on the content type and then date created (asc or desc as you wish). You should have https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll set up as well to allow infinite scroll.